Function implicitly returns the value left by printf
I have the following C code.
Now I know that functions having a return type of int will have implicit return type if there is no return statement. I also get that reading the implicit value is an undefined behaviour. But I can't seem to understand this consistent behaviour: The output of this code is "hello5".
If I printed "HelloWorld" then the output will be "HelloWorld10". It is returning the return type of the printf function?!
I don't really understand how, can anyone explain?
#include <stdio.h>

int m()
{
    printf("Hello");
}

void main() {
    
    int k = m();
    printf("%d",k);
}


If your function doesn't have an explicit return statement, and the calling code try to use what the function "returns", you will have undefined behavior. The compiler should complain about missing return statement, and if not then enable more warnings and treat them as errors that must be fixed.

And the phrasing of the question makes it look to me that you have misunderstood something... In older versions of C it was allowed to leave out the return type in the function declaration, but you still needed to have a return statement if you wanted to return a value. Like for example f() { return 1; } would have been valid. While some compilers still allow it, it haven't been in the C standard for a long time.

Also note that until the C23 standard, not declaring any arguments at all (not even void) would mean that the function could take any number of arguments, of unknown type.

Functions return a value by placing it in an agreed upon location, so the caller can find it. printf did that. When not returning a value, the previous return value just could still be there.

"It is returning the return type of the printf function?!" - Return value is the number of characters transmitted to the output stream or negative value if an output error or an encoding error.

This happens because the generated machine code doesn't clear stack memory: leaving the value returned by the printf on the stack, the program, treat that value as the return value. Likewise, if you write something like this
#include <stdio.h>

int l()
{
    return 3;
}    

int m()
{
    printf("Hello");
    l();
}

void main()
{
    int k = m();
    printf("%d",k);
}

the output will always be "Hello3". If you want to clear the stack memory you have to change the calling convention of the function m().

On most implementations, function return values are passed through registers, not on the stack.

the output will always be "Hello3". It might, but anything could happen. If you want to fix it, it isn't by changing the calling convention.

This looks almost right, but I see what @TomKarzes has said and this seems like an important point. When a function like printf is called, it returns an integer value (the number of characters printed) in a specific CPU register. If the m function does not specify a return value, the compiler does not clear or modify this register before returning from m. Consequently, the calling function (main) interprets this leftover value as the return value of m. So really, the value returned by the printf is on the registers.

@RygelKenoid That's basically correct, but it's not safe to rely on it.  From the compiler's perspective, the return value register is dead and it can freely store something else in it.  And in cases where it does happen to work, you'd probably get the identical code if you simply stored the return value in a variable and then returned that variable.
